# passing a output of a function as a parameter to react component in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am quite new to react-redux. So I need some help trying to understand the syntax here...

I have a file:
**SampleA.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchNames, fetchDownloadLink } from '../../actions/actions'
import SampleChild from '../ui/SampleChild'

class SampleParent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props) ;
}

componentDidMount() {
const { dispatch } = this.props
dispatch(fetchNames());
}

render() {
return(<div><ul id="myUL">{this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                <li>
                    <SampleChild
                        key={report.id}
                        label={report.label}
                        uri={fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")}
                    />
                </li>))}</ul></div>)}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { reports } = state
return {
reports
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReportsApp)
```

I need to pass the output of the function 'fetchDownloadLink' to the SampleChild component. I am not sure how to go about that. 'fetchDownloadLink' returns a url string.

Any thoughts please...
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the result of function, so call the function and save the result in local variable,

```
render() {
const uri = fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")
return(<div><ul id="myUL">{this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                <li>
                    <SampleChild
                        key={report.id}
                        label={report.label}
                        uri={uri}
                    />
                </li>))}</ul></div>)}
}
```

To calculate different `uri` inside `map`, do like this,

```
render() {

return(<div><ul id="myUL">
            {this.props.reports.map((report) => {
                const uri = fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")
                return <li>
                    <SampleChild
                        key={report.id}
                        label={report.label}
                        uri={uri}
                    />
                </li>})}</ul></div>)}
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can use the step: 'const uri = fetchDownloadLink("http://localhost:8080/sample"+this.props.uri+".pdf")' inside the map function? As I need to loop over all uri's... so i cannot put it outside the map function